# Swift Combine: `append` which does not require output to be equal?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

Using Apple's Combine I would like to append a publisher `bar` after a first publisher `foo` has finished (ok to constrain `Failure` to `Never`). Basically I want [RxJava's `andThen`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#andThen-io.reactivex.ObservableSource-).

I have something like this:

```swift
let foo: AnyPublisher<Fruit, Never> = /* actual publisher irrelevant */

let bar: AnyPublisher<Fruit, Never> = /* actual publisher irrelevant */

// A want to do concatenate `bar` to start producing elements
// only after `foo` has `finished`, and let's say I only care about the
// first element of `foo`.
let fooThenBar = foo.first()
    .ignoreOutput()
    .append(bar) // Compilation error: `Cannot convert value of type 'AnyPublisher<Fruit, Never>' to expected argument type 'Publishers.IgnoreOutput<Upstream>.Output' (aka 'Never')`
```

I've come up with a solution, I think it works, but it looks very ugly/overly complicated.

```swift
let fooThenBar = foo.first()
    .ignoreOutput()
    .flatMap { _ in Empty<Fruit, Never>() }
    .append(bar)
```

I'm I missing something here?

## Edit

Added a nicer version of my initial proposal as an answer below. Big thanks to @RobNapier!

Comment: Can you confirm that your code actually works? I've been playing with it, and I never see anything emit from `fooThenBar`. Do you have a sample (ideally using something like PassthroughSubject or CurrentSubject, or the like) that demonstrates that your code works?

Comment: @RobNapier I updated the question with a completely self contained unit test demonstrating that your answer works, and my uglier solution as well.

Comment: This is a fantastically well written test case, but it it's also a little confusing. Don't you want the final publisher to publish Apples rather than Fruit? (Such that P.Output != Q.Output.)

Comment: The more I play with this, the more I think the use of Empty is correct, and isn't a hack. You're asking to start a brand-new stream of values; Empty seems the right place to start that. Obviously it's trivial to wrap that up in an `andThen` method if you want, but I'm growing to believe this is actually good.

Comment: Yes my solution with `Empty` allows for different output, where as your solution is neater when the output is the same.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback and helping me come to important conclusions. I posted my own first version, as an extension.

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of `ignoreOutput`, you just want to filter all the items, and then append:

```
let fooThenBar = foo.first()
    .filter { _ in false }
    .append(bar)
```

You may find this nicer to rename `dropAll()`:

```
extension Publisher {
    func dropAll() -> Publishers.Filter<Self> { filter { _ in false } }
}

let fooThenBar = foo.first()
    .dropAll()
    .append(bar)
```

The underlying issue is that `ignoreAll()` generates a Publisher with Output of Never, which usually makes sense. But in this case you want to just get ride of values without changing the type, and that's filtering.

Comment: Yes much neater and yea makes a lot of sense! Would be nice with something similar to RxSwift Completable, Maybe and Single traits. Combine’s `Future` is kind of like a Single, but with no utility flatMap operator from a Publisher into a Future. And with no `andThen` (what the code above basically is) and other operators relating to those “traits” (as RxSwift call them).

Comment: Damn it, haha, I did a mistake simplifying my scenario... When I asked the question I said that `foo` and `bar` had the same `Output`, actually that was not my case. So given two different outputs, is there any more elegant solution than my `Empty<OutputOfBar, Never>()` 'hack'?

Comment: `.flatMap(Empty).append(bar)` should be identical to `.flatMap(bar)`.

Comment: no `ignoreOutput().flatMap { _ in bar }` does not yield the same result as `ignoreOutput().flatMap { Empty() }.append(bar)`, if you play around with my sample code I posted in my update of my question above you will see that. Or maybe I'm completely confused here! :D

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to great discussions with @RobNapier we kind of concluded that a `flatMap { Empty }.append(otherPublisher)` solution is the best when the output of the two publishers differ. Since I wanted to use this after the first/base/'foo' publisher finishes, I've written an extension on `Publishers.IgnoreOutput`, the result is this:

## Solution

```swift
protocol BaseForAndThen {}
extension Publishers.IgnoreOutput: BaseForAndThen {}
extension Combine.Future: BaseForAndThen {}

extension Publisher where Self: BaseForAndThen, Self.Failure == Never {
    func andThen<Then>(_ thenPublisher: Then) -> AnyPublisher<Then.Output, Never> where Then: Publisher, Then.Failure == Failure {
        return
            flatMap { _ in Empty<Then.Output, Never>(completeImmediately: true) } // same as `init()`
                .append(thenPublisher)
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

## Usage

In my use case I wanted to control/have insight in *when* the base publisher finishes, therefore my solution is based on this.

#### Together with `ignoreOutput`

Since the second publisher, in case below `appleSubject`, won't start producing elements (outputting values) until the first publisher finishes, I use [`first()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/3204710-first) operator (there is also a [`last()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/3204715-last) operator) to make the `bananaSubject` finish after one output.

```swift
bananaSubject.first().ignoreOutput().andThen(appleSubject)
```

#### Together with `Future`

A `Future` already just produces one element and then finishes.

```swift
futureBanana.andThen(applePublisher)
```

## Test

Here is the complete unit test ([also on Github](https://github.com/Sajjon/FooThenBarPublisher))

```swift
import XCTest
import Combine

protocol Fruit {
    var price: Int { get }
}

typealias  = Banana
struct Banana: Fruit {
    let price: Int
}

typealias  = Apple
struct Apple: Fruit {
    let price: Int
}

final class CombineAppendDifferentOutputTests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        continueAfterFailure = false
    }

    func testFirst() throws {
        try doTest { bananaPublisher, applePublisher in
            bananaPublisher.first().ignoreOutput().andThen(applePublisher)
        }
    }

    func testFuture() throws {
        var cancellable: Cancellable?
        try doTest { bananaPublisher, applePublisher in

            let futureBanana = Future<, Never> { promise in
                cancellable = bananaPublisher.sink(
                    receiveCompletion: { _ in },
                    receiveValue: { value in promise(.success(value)) }
                )
            }

            return futureBanana.andThen(applePublisher)
        }

        XCTAssertNotNil(cancellable)
    }

    static var allTests = [
        ("testFirst", testFirst),
        ("testFuture", testFuture),

    ]
}

private extension CombineAppendDifferentOutputTests {

    func doTest(_ line: UInt = #line, _ fooThenBarMethod: (AnyPublisher<, Never>, AnyPublisher<, Never>) -> AnyPublisher<, Never>) throws {
        // GIVEN
        // Two publishers `foo` () and `bar` ()
        let bananaSubject = PassthroughSubject<Banana, Never>()
        let appleSubject = PassthroughSubject<Apple, Never>()

        var outputtedFruits = [Fruit]()
        let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: self.debugDescription)

        let cancellable = fooThenBarMethod(
            bananaSubject.eraseToAnyPublisher(),
            appleSubject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
            )
            .sink(
                receiveCompletion: { _ in expectation.fulfill() },
                receiveValue: { outputtedFruits.append($0 as Fruit) }
        )

        // WHEN
        // a send apples and bananas to the respective subjects and a `finish` completion to `appleSubject` (`bar`)
        appleSubject.send((price: 1))
        bananaSubject.send((price: 2))
        appleSubject.send((price: 3))
        bananaSubject.send((price: 4))
        appleSubject.send((price: 5))

        appleSubject.send(completion: .finished)

        wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 0.1)

        // THEN
        // A: I the output contains no banana (since the bananaSubject publisher's output is ignored)
        // and
        // B: Exactly two apples, more specifically the two last, since when the first Apple (with price 1) is sent, we have not yet received the first (needed and triggering) banana.
        let expectedFruitCount = 2
        XCTAssertEqual(outputtedFruits.count, expectedFruitCount, line: line)
        XCTAssertTrue(outputtedFruits.allSatisfy({ $0 is  }), line: line)
        let apples = outputtedFruits.compactMap { $0 as?  }
        XCTAssertEqual(apples.count, expectedFruitCount, line: line)
        let firstApple = try XCTUnwrap(apples.first)
        let lastApple = try XCTUnwrap(apples.last)
        XCTAssertEqual(firstApple.price, 3, line: line)
        XCTAssertEqual(lastApple.price, 5, line: line)
        XCTAssertNotNil(cancellable, line: line)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use `.ignoreOutput()`, it is safe to replace "ugly" `.flatMap { _ in Empty<Fruit, Never>() }` to simple `.map { Fruit?.none! }` which will never be called anyway and just changes the Output type.