# Swift Combine: Buffer upstream values and emit them at a steady rate?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

Using the new Combine framework in iOS 13.

Suppose I have an upstream publisher sending values at a highly irregular rate - sometimes seconds or minutes may go by without any values, and then a stream of values may come through all at once. I'd like to create a custom publisher that subscribes to the upstream values, buffers them and emits them at a regular, known cadence when they come in, but publishes nothing if they've all been exhausted.

**For a concrete example:**

- t = 0 to 5000ms: no upstream values published
- t = 5001ms: upstream publishes "a"
- t = 5002ms: upstream publishes "b"
- t = 5003ms: upstream publishes "c"
- t = 5004ms to 10000ms: no upstream values published
- t = 10001ms: upstream publishes "d"

**My publisher subscribed to the upstream would produce values every 1 second:**

- t = 0 to 5000ms: no values published
- t = 5001ms: publishes "a"
- t = 6001ms: publishes "b"
- t = 7001ms: publishes "c"
- t = 7001ms to 10001ms: no values published
- t = 10001ms: publishes "d"

None of the existing publishers or operators in Combine seem to *quite* do what I want here.

- [`throttle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/3204760-throttle) and [`debounce`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/3204702-debounce) would simply sample the upstream values at a certain cadence and drop ones that are missing (e.g. would only publish "a" if the cadence was 1000ms)
- [`delay`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/3204704-delay) would add the same delay to every value, but not space them out (e.g. if my delay was 1000ms, it would publish "a" at 6001ms, "b" at 6002ms, "c" at 6003ms)
- [`buffer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/3235802-buffer) seems promising, but I can't quite figure out how to use it - how to force it to publish a value from the buffer on demand. When I hooked up a sink to `buffer` it seemed to just instantly publish all the values, not buffering at all.

I thought about using some sort of combining operator like `zip` or `merge` or `combineLatest` and combining it with a Timer publisher, and that's probably the right approach, but I can't figure out exactly how to configure it to give the behavior I want.

**Edit**

Here's a marble diagram that hopefully illustrates what I'm going for:

```
Upstream Publisher:
-A-B-C-------------------D-E-F--------|>

My Custom Operator:
-A----B----C-------------D----E----F--|>
```

**Edit 2: Unit Test**

Here's a unit test that should pass if `modulatedPublisher` (my desired buffered publisher) works as desired. It's not perfect, but it stores events (including the time received) as they're received and then compares the time intervals between events, ensuring they are no smaller than the desired interval.

```
func testCustomPublisher() {
    let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "async")
    var events = [Event]()

    let passthroughSubject = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()
    let cancellable = passthroughSubject
        .modulatedPublisher(interval: 1.0)
        .sink { value in
            events.append(Event(value: value, date: Date()))
            print("value received: \(value) at \(self.dateFormatter.string(from:Date()))")
        }

    // WHEN I send 3 events, wait 6 seconds, and send 3 more events
    passthroughSubject.send(1)
    passthroughSubject.send(2)
    passthroughSubject.send(3)

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(6000)) {
        passthroughSubject.send(4)
        passthroughSubject.send(5)
        passthroughSubject.send(6)

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(4000)) {

            // THEN I expect the stored events to be no closer together in time than the interval of 1.0s
            for i in 1 ..< events.count {
                let interval = events[i].date.timeIntervalSince(events[i-1].date)
                print("Interval: \(interval)")

                // There's some small error in the interval but it should be about 1 second since I'm using a 1s modulated publisher.
                XCTAssertTrue(interval > 0.99)
            }
            expectation.fulfill()
        }
    }

    wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 15)
}
```

The closest I've gotten is using `zip`, like so:

```
public extension Publisher where Self.Failure == Never {
    func modulatedPublisher(interval: TimeInterval) -> AnyPublisher<Output, Never> {
        let timerBuffer = Timer
        .publish(every: interval, on: .main, in: .common)
        .autoconnect()

      return timerBuffer
        .zip(self, { $1 })                  // should emit one input element ($1) every timer tick
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

This properly attunes the first three events (1, 2, and 3), but not the second three (4, 5, and 6). The output:

```
value received: 1 at 3:54:07.0007
value received: 2 at 3:54:08.0008
value received: 3 at 3:54:09.0009
value received: 4 at 3:54:12.0012
value received: 5 at 3:54:12.0012
value received: 6 at 3:54:12.0012
```

I believe this is happening because `zip` has some internal buffering capacity. The first three upstream events are buffered and emitted on the Timer's cadence, but during the 6 second wait, the Timer's events are buffered - and when the second set ups upstream events are fired, there are already Timer events waiting in the queue, so they're paired up and fired off immediately.

Comment: It would be EXTREMELY useful for us (me) and probably yourself too, if you could share some (failing) unit tests of what you expect. It is always much more clear what you want to achieve when implemented as a test. You can take some inspiration from my test here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58734595/1311272 you can also you CombineExpectations for writing tests: https://github.com/groue/CombineExpectations

Comment: Thanks Sajjon - I'll try to write one. I've never written a unit test for publishers though, so it might take a bit. I'm curious, would it be useful to you (and me) simply because you can start experimenting with code and know when you've succeeded because of the passing test? Or would it be useful because it clarifies the exact requirement? I believe the example I gave in the question is fairly clear.

Comment: Mostly because the requirements become clear

Comment: I think my links will be a good starting point

Comment: @Sajjon I've updated my post with a failing unit test and a stab at an implementation that almost, but doesn't quite, do what I want.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is an interesting problem. I played with various combinations of `Timer.publish`, `buffer`, `zip`, and `throttle`, but I couldn't get any combination to work quite the way you want. So let's write a custom subscriber.

What we'd really like is an API where, when we get an input from upstream, we also get the ability to control when the upstream delivers the next input. Something like this:

```
extension Publisher {
    /// Subscribe to me with a stepping function.
    /// - parameter stepper: A function I'll call with each of my inputs, and with my completion.
    ///   Each time I call this function with an input, I also give it a promise function.
    ///   I won't deliver the next input until the promise is called with a `.more` argument.
    /// - returns: An object you can use to cancel the subscription asynchronously.
    func step(with stepper: @escaping (StepEvent<Output, Failure>) -> ()) -> AnyCancellable {
        ???
    }
}

enum StepEvent<Input, Failure: Error> {
    /// Handle the Input. Call `StepPromise` when you're ready for the next Input,
    /// or to cancel the subscription.
    case input(Input, StepPromise)

    /// Upstream completed the subscription.
    case completion(Subscribers.Completion<Failure>)
}

/// The type of callback given to the stepper function to allow it to continue
/// or cancel the stream.
typealias StepPromise = (StepPromiseRequest) -> ()

enum StepPromiseRequest {
    // Pass this to the promise to request the next item from upstream.
    case more

    // Pass this to the promise to cancel the subscription.
    case cancel
}
```

With this `step` API, we can write a `pace` operator that does what you want:

```
extension Publisher {
    func pace<Context: Scheduler, MySubject: Subject>(
        _ pace: Context.SchedulerTimeType.Stride, scheduler: Context, subject: MySubject)
        -> AnyCancellable
        where MySubject.Output == Output, MySubject.Failure == Failure
    {
        return step {
            switch $0 {
            case .input(let input, let promise):
                // Send the input from upstream now.
                subject.send(input)

                // Wait for the pace interval to elapse before requesting the
                // next input from upstream.
                scheduler.schedule(after: scheduler.now.advanced(by: pace)) {
                    promise(.more)
                }

            case .completion(let completion):
                subject.send(completion: completion)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This `pace` operator takes `pace` (the required interval between outputs), a scheduler on which to schedule events, and a `subject` on which to republish the inputs from upstream. It handles each input by sending it through `subject`, and then using the scheduler to wait for the pace interval before asking for the next input from upstream.

Now we just have to implement the `step` operator. Combine doesn't give us too much help here. It does have a feature called “backpressure”, which means a publisher cannot send an input downstream until the downstream has asked for it by sending a `Subscribers.Demand` upstream. Usually you see downstreams send an `.unlimited` demand upstream, but we're not going to. Instead, we're going to take advantage of backpressure. We won't send any demand upstream until the stepper completes a promise, and then we'll only send a demand of `.max(1)`, so we make the upstream operate in lock-step with the stepper. (We also have to send an initial demand of `.max(1)` to start the whole process.)

Okay, so need to implement a type that takes a stepper function and conforms to `Subscriber`. It's a good idea to review the [Reactive Streams JVM Specification](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm/blob/v1.0.3/README.md#specification), because Combine is based on that specification.

What makes the implementation difficult is that several things can call into our subscriber asynchronously:

- The upstream can call into the subscriber from any thread (but is required to serialize its calls).
- After we've given promise functions to the stepper, the stepper can call those promises on any thread.
- We want the subscription to be cancellable, and that cancellation can happen on any thread.
- All this asynchronicity means we have to protect our internal state with a lock.
- We have to be careful not to call out while holding that lock, to avoid deadlock.

We'll also protect the subscriber from shenanigans involving calling a promise repeatedly, or calling outdated promises, by giving each promise a unique id.

Se here's our basic subscriber definition:

```
import Combine
import Foundation

public class SteppingSubscriber<Input, Failure: Error> {

    public init(stepper: @escaping Stepper) {
        l_state = .subscribing(stepper)
    }

    public typealias Stepper = (Event) -> ()

    public enum Event {
        case input(Input, Promise)
        case completion(Completion)
    }

    public typealias Promise = (Request) -> ()

    public enum Request {
        case more
        case cancel
    }

    public typealias Completion = Subscribers.Completion<Failure>

    private let lock = NSLock()

    // The l_ prefix means it must only be accessed while holding the lock.
    private var l_state: State
    private var l_nextPromiseId: PromiseId = 1

    private typealias PromiseId = Int

    private var noPromiseId: PromiseId { 0 }
}
```

Notice that I moved the auxiliary types from earlier (`StepEvent`, `StepPromise`, and `StepPromiseRequest`) into `SteppingSubscriber` and shortened their names.

Now let's consider `l_state`'s mysterious type, `State`. What are all the different states our subscriber could be in?

- We could be waiting to receive the `Subscription` object from upstream.
- We could have received the `Subscription` from upstream and be waiting for a signal (an input or completion from upstream, or the completion of a promise from the stepper).
- We could be calling out to the stepper, which we want to be careful in case it completes a promise while we're calling out to it.
- We could have been cancelled or have received completion from upstream.

So here is our definition of `State`:

```
extension SteppingSubscriber {
    private enum State {
        // Completed or cancelled.
        case dead

        // Waiting for Subscription from upstream.
        case subscribing(Stepper)

        // Waiting for a signal from upstream or for the latest promise to be completed.
        case subscribed(Subscribed)

        // Calling out to the stopper.
        case stepping(Stepping)

        var subscription: Subscription? {
            switch self {
            case .dead: return nil
            case .subscribing(_): return nil
            case .subscribed(let subscribed): return subscribed.subscription
            case .stepping(let stepping): return stepping.subscribed.subscription
            }
        }

        struct Subscribed {
            var stepper: Stepper
            var subscription: Subscription
            var validPromiseId: PromiseId
        }

        struct Stepping {
            var subscribed: Subscribed

            // If the stepper completes the current promise synchronously with .more,
            // I set this to true.
            var shouldRequestMore: Bool
        }
    }
}
```

Since we're using `NSLock` (for simplicity), let's define an extension to ensure we always match locking with unlocking:

```
fileprivate extension NSLock {
    @inline(__always)
    func sync<Answer>(_ body: () -> Answer) -> Answer {
        lock()
        defer { unlock() }
        return body()
    }
}
```

Now we're ready to handle some events. The easiest event to handle is asynchronous cancellation, which is the `Cancellable` protocol's only requirement. If we're in any state except `.dead`, we want to become `.dead` and, if there's an upstream subscription, cancel it.

```
extension SteppingSubscriber: Cancellable {
    public func cancel() {
        let sub: Subscription? = lock.sync {
            defer { l_state = .dead }
            return l_state.subscription
        }
        sub?.cancel()
    }
}
```

Notice here that I don't want to call out to the upstream subscription's `cancel` function while `lock` is locked, because `lock` isn't a recursive lock and I don't want to risk deadlock. All use of `lock.sync` follows the pattern of deferring any call-outs until after the lock is unlocked.

Now let's implement the `Subscriber` protocol requirements. First, let's handle receiving the `Subscription` from upstream. The only time this should happen is when we're in the `.subscribing` state, but `.dead` is also possible in which case we want to just cancel the upstream subscription.

```
extension SteppingSubscriber: Subscriber {
    public func receive(subscription: Subscription) {
        let action: () -> () = lock.sync {
            guard case .subscribing(let stepper) = l_state else {
                return { subscription.cancel() }
            }
            l_state = .subscribed(.init(stepper: stepper, subscription: subscription, validPromiseId: noPromiseId))
            return { subscription.request(.max(1)) }
        }
        action()
    }
```

Notice that in this use of `lock.sync` (and in all later uses), I return an “action” closure so I can perform arbitrary call-outs after the lock has been unlocked.

The next `Subscriber` protocol requirement we'll tackle is receiving a completion:

```
    public func receive(completion: Subscribers.Completion<Failure>) {
        let action: (() -> ())? = lock.sync {
            // The only state in which I have to handle this call is .subscribed:
            // - If I'm .dead, either upstream already completed (and shouldn't call this again),
            //   or I've been cancelled.
            // - If I'm .subscribing, upstream must send me a Subscription before sending me a completion.
            // - If I'm .stepping, upstream is currently signalling me and isn't allowed to signal
            //   me again concurrently.
            guard case .subscribed(let subscribed) = l_state else {
                return nil
            }
            l_state = .dead
            return { [stepper = subscribed.stepper] in
                stepper(.completion(completion))
            }
        }
        action?()
    }
```

The most complex `Subscriber` protocol requirement for us is receiving an `Input`:

- We have to create a promise.
- We have to pass the promise to the stepper.
- The stepper could complete the promise before returning.
- After the stepper returns, we have to check whether it completed the promise with `.more` and, if so, return the appropriate demand upstream.

Since we have to call out to the stepper in the middle of this work, we have some ugly nesting of `lock.sync` calls.

```
    public func receive(_ input: Input) -> Subscribers.Demand {
        let action: (() -> Subscribers.Demand)? = lock.sync {
            // The only state in which I have to handle this call is .subscribed:
            // - If I'm .dead, either upstream completed and shouldn't call this,
            //   or I've been cancelled.
            // - If I'm .subscribing, upstream must send me a Subscription before sending me Input.
            // - If I'm .stepping, upstream is currently signalling me and isn't allowed to
            //   signal me again concurrently.
            guard case .subscribed(var subscribed) = l_state else {
                return nil
            }

            let promiseId = l_nextPromiseId
            l_nextPromiseId += 1
            let promise: Promise = { request in
                self.completePromise(id: promiseId, request: request)
            }
            subscribed.validPromiseId = promiseId
            l_state = .stepping(.init(subscribed: subscribed, shouldRequestMore: false))
            return { [stepper = subscribed.stepper] in
                stepper(.input(input, promise))

                let demand: Subscribers.Demand = self.lock.sync {
                    // The only possible states now are .stepping and .dead.
                    guard case .stepping(let stepping) = self.l_state else {
                        return .none
                    }
                    self.l_state = .subscribed(stepping.subscribed)
                    return stepping.shouldRequestMore ? .max(1) : .none
                }

                return demand
            }
        }

        return action?() ?? .none
    }
} // end of extension SteppingSubscriber: Publisher
```

The last thing our subscriber needs to handle is the completion of a promise. This is complicated for several reasons:

- We want to protect against a promise being completed multiple times.
- We want to protect against an older promise being completed.
- We can be in any state when a promise is completed.

Thus:

```
extension SteppingSubscriber {
    private func completePromise(id: PromiseId, request: Request) {
        let action: (() -> ())? = lock.sync {
            switch l_state {
            case .dead, .subscribing(_): return nil
            case .subscribed(var subscribed) where subscribed.validPromiseId == id && request == .more:
                subscribed.validPromiseId = noPromiseId
                l_state = .subscribed(subscribed)
                return { [sub = subscribed.subscription] in
                    sub.request(.max(1))
                }
            case .subscribed(let subscribed) where subscribed.validPromiseId == id && request == .cancel:
                l_state = .dead
                return { [sub = subscribed.subscription] in
                    sub.cancel()
                }
            case .subscribed(_):
                // Multiple completion or stale promise.
                return nil
            case .stepping(var stepping) where stepping.subscribed.validPromiseId == id && request == .more:
                stepping.subscribed.validPromiseId = noPromiseId
                stepping.shouldRequestMore = true
                l_state = .stepping(stepping)
                return nil
            case .stepping(let stepping) where stepping.subscribed.validPromiseId == id && request == .cancel:
                l_state = .dead
                return { [sub = stepping.subscribed.subscription] in
                    sub.cancel()
                }
            case .stepping(_):
                // Multiple completion or stale promise.
                return nil
            }
        }

        action?()
    }
}
```

Whew!

With all that done, we can write the real `step` operator:

```
extension Publisher {
    func step(with stepper: @escaping (SteppingSubscriber<Output, Failure>.Event) -> ()) -> AnyCancellable {
        let subscriber = SteppingSubscriber<Output, Failure>(stepper: stepper)
        self.subscribe(subscriber)
        return .init(subscriber)
    }
}
```

And then we can try out that `pace` operator from above. Since we don't do any buffering in `SteppingSubscriber`, and the upstream in general isn't buffered, we'll stick a `buffer` in between the upstream and our `pace` operator.

```
    var cans: [AnyCancellable] = []

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        let erratic = Just("A").delay(for: 0.0, tolerance: 0.001, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main).eraseToAnyPublisher()
            .merge(with: Just("B").delay(for: 0.3, tolerance: 0.001, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main).eraseToAnyPublisher())
            .merge(with: Just("C").delay(for: 0.6, tolerance: 0.001, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main).eraseToAnyPublisher())
            .merge(with: Just("D").delay(for: 5.0, tolerance: 0.001, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main).eraseToAnyPublisher())
            .merge(with: Just("E").delay(for: 5.3, tolerance: 0.001, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main).eraseToAnyPublisher())
            .merge(with: Just("F").delay(for: 5.6, tolerance: 0.001, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main).eraseToAnyPublisher())
            .handleEvents(
                receiveOutput: { print("erratic: \(Double(DispatchTime.now().rawValue) / 1_000_000_000) \($0)") },
                receiveCompletion: { print("erratic: \(Double(DispatchTime.now().rawValue) / 1_000_000_000) \($0)") }
        )
            .makeConnectable()

        let subject = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()

        cans += [erratic
            .buffer(size: 1000, prefetch: .byRequest, whenFull: .dropOldest)
            .pace(.seconds(1), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main, subject: subject)]

        cans += [subject.sink(
            receiveCompletion: { print("paced: \(Double(DispatchTime.now().rawValue) / 1_000_000_000) \($0)") },
            receiveValue: { print("paced: \(Double(DispatchTime.now().rawValue) / 1_000_000_000) \($0)") }
            )]

        let c = erratic.connect()
        cans += [AnyCancellable { c.cancel() }]

        return true
    }
```

And here, at long last, is the output:

```
erratic: 223394.17115897 A
paced: 223394.171495405 A
erratic: 223394.408086369 B
erratic: 223394.739186984 C
paced: 223395.171615624 B
paced: 223396.27056174 C
erratic: 223399.536717127 D
paced: 223399.536782847 D
erratic: 223399.536834495 E
erratic: 223400.236808469 F
erratic: 223400.236886323 finished
paced: 223400.620542561 E
paced: 223401.703613078 F
paced: 223402.703828512 finished
```

- Timestamps are in units of seconds.
- The erratic publisher's timings are, indeed, erratic and sometimes close in time.
- The paced timings are always at least one second apart even when the erratic events occur less than one second apart.
- When an erratic event occurs more than one second after the prior event, the paced event is sent immediately following the erratic event without further delay.
- The paced completion occurs one second after the last paced event, even though the erratic completion occurs immediately after the last erratic event. The `buffer` doesn't send the completion until it receives another demand after it sends the last event, and that demand is delayed by the pacing timer.

I've put the the entire implementation of the `step` operator in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mayoff/f89f072e6097e932f9edb4955823efc9) for easy copy/paste.

Comment: Yeah baby! And indeed, as I said (in a comment now deleted), it would take a custom subscriber to do what the OP wanted.

Comment: Wow. This is fascinating and brilliant, and also helps me understand the purpose of `buffer`, which is to buffer events if the downstream subscriber has a demand that's less than `.unlimited`. I had just started exploring writing a custom publisher, but I didn't get this far. Thank you so much! If you write a blog, maybe this could/should become a blog post!

Comment: I do have one question. The implementation you've provided requires the user to provide a separate subject to act as the downstream. So instead of a single unbroken pipeline like `upstream.buffer(...).pace(...).sink(...)`, it becomes `upstream.buffer(...).pace(..., subject: subject)`; `subject.sink(...)` Was that simply a choice you made for simplicity, or did your implementation omit the possibility of letting `pace` return another publisher directly, so that a single pipeline could be constructed?

Comment: I made that choice for simplicity. If we don't use a subject, we have to implement the `Publisher` protocol in addition to implementing the `Subscriber` protocol.

Comment: I'm trying to take your solution and modify it to do just that, mainly because the final result will look more Swift-y (or Combine-y?). Mind if I ask your help if I run into trouble? It doesn't seem like it should be conceptually difficult - move the `pace` / `step` custom subscriber to be internal to my new Publisher type, and expose another publisher in place of the external subject to send events out. But I'm not super comfortable with generics and I've never written a custom Publisher, so I might run into trouble.

Comment: If you run into trouble, your best bet is to post a new question here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 19):

**EDIT**

There's an even simpler approach to the original one outlined below, which doesn't require a pacer, but instead uses back-pressure created by `flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(1))`.

`flatMap` sends a demand of 1, until its returned publisher, which we could delay, completes. We'd need a `Buffer` publisher upstream to buffer the values.

```
// for demo purposes, this subject sends a Date:
let subject = PassthroughSubject<Date, Never>()
let interval = 1.0

let pub = subject
   .buffer(size: .max, prefetch: .byRequest, whenFull: .dropNewest)
   .flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(1)) {
      Just($0)
        .delay(for: .seconds(interval), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
   }
```

---

**ORIGINAL**

I know this is an old question, but I think there's a much simpler way to implement this, so I thought I'd share.

The idea is similar to a `.zip` with a `Timer`, except instead of a `Timer`, you would `.zip` with a time-delayed "tick" from a previously sent value, which can be achieved with a `CurrentValueSubject`. `CurrentValueSubject` is needed instead of a `PassthroughSubject` in order to seed the first ever "tick".

```
// for demo purposes, this subject sends a Date:
let subject = PassthroughSubject<Date, Never>()

let pacer = CurrentValueSubject<Void, Never>(())
let interval = 1.0

let pub = subject.zip(pacer)
   .flatMap { v in
      Just(v.0) // extract the original value
        .delay(for: .seconds(interval), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
        .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { _ in 
           pacer.send() // send the pacer "tick" after the interval
        }) 
   }
```

What happens is that the `.zip` gates on the pacer, which only arrives after a delay from a previously sent value.

If the next value comes earlier than the allowed interval, it waits for the pacer.
If, however, the next value comes later, then the pacer already has a new value to provide instantly, so there would be no delay.

---

If you used it like in your test case:

```
let c = pub.sink { print("\($0): \(Date())") }

subject.send(Date())
subject.send(Date())
subject.send(Date())

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
   subject.send(Date())
   subject.send(Date())
}

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10.0) {
   subject.send(Date())
   subject.send(Date())
}
```

the result would be something like this:

```
2020-06-23 19:15:21 +0000: 2020-06-23 19:15:21 +0000
2020-06-23 19:15:21 +0000: 2020-06-23 19:15:22 +0000
2020-06-23 19:15:21 +0000: 2020-06-23 19:15:23 +0000
2020-06-23 19:15:22 +0000: 2020-06-23 19:15:24 +0000
2020-06-23 19:15:22 +0000: 2020-06-23 19:15:25 +0000
2020-06-23 19:15:32 +0000: 2020-06-23 19:15:32 +0000
2020-06-23 19:15:32 +0000: 2020-06-23 19:15:33 +0000
```

Comment: Ingenious!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Could `Publishers.CollectByTime` be useful here somewhere?

```
Publishers.CollectByTime(upstream: upstreamPublisher.share(), strategy: Publishers.TimeGroupingStrategy.byTime(RunLoop.main, .seconds(1)), options: nil)
```

Comment: I haven't tried, but the `Output` type of `CollectByTime` is `[Upstream.Output]`, i.e. an array of the upstream's `Output`. That suggests to me that CollectByTime would collect all values within the given stride and then emit them as a single array. So if I receive 3 values within 1 ms of each other, and I want to emit every 1 second, then after 1 second this publisher would emit an array of all 3 values, rather than each individual value once per second.

Comment: Yes, for sure it won't do what you want by itself.  But it could be useful in an overall solution. Such as unpacking the array and emitting them individually through a `throttle` or something else. (Also, I'm not positive the array itself is in the order they were emitted upstream, needs to be verified).

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to mention that I adapted Rob's answer from earlier and converted it to a custom Publisher, in order to allow for a single unbroken pipeline (see comments below his solution). My adaptation is below, but all the credit still goes to him. It also still makes use of Rob's `step` operator and `SteppingSubscriber`, as this custom Publisher uses those internally.

Edit: updated with buffer as part of the `modulated` operator, otherwise that would be required to be attached to buffer the upstream events.

```
public extension Publisher {
    func modulated<Context: Scheduler>(_ pace: Context.SchedulerTimeType.Stride, scheduler: Context) -> AnyPublisher<Output, Failure> {
        let upstream = buffer(size: 1000, prefetch: .byRequest, whenFull: .dropNewest).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        return PacePublisher<Context, AnyPublisher>(pace: pace, scheduler: scheduler, source: upstream).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

final class PacePublisher<Context: Scheduler, Source: Publisher>: Publisher {
    typealias Output = Source.Output
    typealias Failure = Source.Failure

    let subject: PassthroughSubject<Output, Failure>
    let scheduler: Context
    let pace: Context.SchedulerTimeType.Stride

    lazy var internalSubscriber: SteppingSubscriber<Output, Failure> = SteppingSubscriber<Output, Failure>(stepper: stepper)
    lazy var stepper: ((SteppingSubscriber<Output, Failure>.Event) -> ()) = {
        switch $0 {
        case .input(let input, let promise):
            // Send the input from upstream now.
            self.subject.send(input)

            // Wait for the pace interval to elapse before requesting the
            // next input from upstream.
            self.scheduler.schedule(after: self.scheduler.now.advanced(by: self.pace)) {
                promise(.more)
            }

        case .completion(let completion):
            self.subject.send(completion: completion)
        }
    }

    init(pace: Context.SchedulerTimeType.Stride, scheduler: Context, source: Source) {
        self.scheduler = scheduler
        self.pace = pace
        self.subject = PassthroughSubject<Source.Output, Source.Failure>()

        source.subscribe(internalSubscriber)
    }

    public func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber, Failure == S.Failure, Output == S.Input {
        subject.subscribe(subscriber)
        subject.send(subscription: PaceSubscription(subscriber: subscriber))
    }
}

public class PaceSubscription<S: Subscriber>: Subscription {
    private var subscriber: S?

    init(subscriber: S) {
        self.subscriber = subscriber
    }

    public func request(_ demand: Subscribers.Demand) {

    }

    public func cancel() {
        subscriber = nil
    }
}
```