# Custom Combine RateLimitedScheduler

Tags: swift, scheduler, combine

I'm trying to implement a rate limiting scheduler in combine. The docs aren't great for Scheduler so I'm making some assumptions about how they operate internally. I'm assuming that the `schedule` function gets called for each event in the stream but that's not what I'm seeing in practice. I'm only seeing a couple of calls to that function in a stream of many more events.

Here is my implementation which is doing effectively nothing right now and allowing all events through...

```swift
public class RateLimitedScheduler: Scheduler {
    public typealias SchedulerTimeType = DispatchQueue.SchedulerTimeType
    public typealias SchedulerOptions = DispatchQueue.SchedulerOptions
    
    // MARK: API
    
    public var now: SchedulerTimeType { queue.now }
    public var minimumTolerance: SchedulerTimeType.Stride { queue.minimumTolerance }

    public func schedule(options: SchedulerOptions? = nil, _ action: @escaping () -> Void) {
        queue.schedule(after: nextDeadline(), tolerance: .init(floatLiteral: period / 10), options: options, action)
    }

    public func schedule(after date: SchedulerTimeType, tolerance: SchedulerTimeType.Stride, options: SchedulerOptions? = nil, _ action: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let deadline = max(nextDeadline(), date)
        queue.schedule(after: deadline, tolerance: tolerance, options: options, action)
    }

    public func schedule(after date: SchedulerTimeType,
                  interval: SchedulerTimeType.Stride,
                  tolerance: SchedulerTimeType.Stride,
                  options: SchedulerOptions? = nil,
                  _ action: @escaping () -> Void) -> Cancellable {
        let deadline = max(nextDeadline(), date)
        return queue.schedule(after: deadline, interval: interval, tolerance: tolerance, options: options, action)
    }
    
    // MARK: Initialization
    
    public init(maxEvents: Int, period: TimeInterval, queue: DispatchQueue = .main) {
        self.maxEvents = maxEvents
        self.period = period
        self.queue = queue
    }
    
    // MARK: Private
    
    private let maxEvents: Int
    private let period: TimeInterval
    private let queue: DispatchQueue

    private var eventCount = 0
    private var windowStartTime = DispatchTime.now()

    private func nextDeadline() -> SchedulerTimeType {
        let now = DispatchTime.now()

        if eventCount < maxEvents {
            eventCount += 1
            return SchedulerTimeType(max(windowStartTime, now))
        }

        let nextStartTime = windowStartTime + period
        eventCount = 1
        
        if now > nextStartTime {
            windowStartTime = now
            return SchedulerTimeType(max(windowStartTime, now))
        }
        
        windowStartTime = nextStartTime
            
        return SchedulerTimeType(max(nextStartTime, now))
    }
}
```

And to test:

```swift
let cancellable = Array(repeating: 0, count: 20).publisher
    .map { $0 * 1 }
    .subscribe(on: RateLimitedScheduler(maxEvents: 5, period: 1))
    .sink(receiveValue: { _ in
        print(Date())
    })
```

My algorithm for `nextDeadline` definitely works as I've tested it outside of the scheduler so that's not the issue.

So my questions are:

1. Is my assumption correct that each event should fire the schedule function in the scheduler? And if not, why not?
2. Can anyone help figure this out or provide me with an alternative?

Comment: I haven't implemented a `Scheduler` so can't help you there, but see if this helps to create a rate limiter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62542206/968155

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve with this scheduler? I am asking because it might be possible to achieve without custom scheduler.

Comment: @LuLuGaGa I'm trying to limit the number of requests to 5. per second for example on a combine stream

Comment: @NewDev Nice, that does the trick! Thanks.

Comment: I am still curious to understand why the scheduler doesn't work though

Comment: wouldn't `.debounce(for: 0.2, scheduler: RunLoop.main)` or similar solve your problem?

Comment: @LuLuGaGa, if I'm not mistaken, debounce drops values, rather than buffering and emitting at a steady rate

Comment: @doovers, feel free to upvote my other answer ;)

Comment: From the docs: Use the debounce(for:scheduler:options:) operator to control the number of values and time between delivery of values from the upstream publisher. This operator is useful to process bursty or high-volume event streams where you need to reduce the number of values delivered to the downstream to a rate you specify.

Comment: @NewDev My bad forgot to upvote!!

Comment: @LuLuGaGa Yes I can confirm debounce and throttle will drop values. Also, the idea is to allow all elements allowed through for a specific window and then delay until the next window.